# incorrect mapping from brightness slider to real system values

Tags: screen-brightness

Sorry in advance for bad english and also for a noob question.

I have a problem with brightness on my tablet Supra M94BG. There is a system brightness slider, the range is 0% -- 100% (as usual), and the problem is that 0% corresponds `0` value in `/sys/devices/platform/leds-mt65xx/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness` , and 100% corresponds `90` value, and not `255`, as expected. Manual setting of value in `/sys/.../brightness` to `255` gives really maximum level of brightness (as desired), but this value resets to `90` after screen is locked.

How can I correct the mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe everytime you unlock the screen, the phone sets the brightness to the current brightness value specified (set) by the slider.

This is something that has to be changed in the framework-res.apk .

If you know how to edit it using APKtool, just proceed.

Otherwise, the most easiest way is using a **Tasker** app.
Just add a task to set (echo) the brightness to 255 everytime screen is unlocked.

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know about Tasker app, it is the best temporary solution for now! However, I think I still need to fix `framework-res.apk` so for this bug not to appear at all.

Comment: And that's not a bug :) It's just to save your battery or avoid heating or something.

Comment: As you have told me, I disassembled `framework-res.apk` and found these values there:
`<integer name="config_screenBrightnessSettingMinimum">30</integer>`
`<integer name="config_screenBrightnessSettingMaximum">255</integer>`
`<integer name="config_screenBrightnessSettingDefault">102</integer>`
No trace of maximum value of 90. Do I have to search in another place?